# Cannot install own package in R

Tags: r, installation, package

I want to install, from local, a package a colleague created. First, you have to know that I don’t own the admin rights on the computer, and the policy at my company is very strict.

So, when I try to install the package, I do
`> install.packages("C:\\Users\\myusername\\packagename.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")`,

but it does not work and gives me the following error :

```
* installing *source* package 'packagename' ...
** libs

*** arch - i386
Warning: running command 'make -f "C:/Users/myusername/R/R-32~1.4RE/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/Users/myusername/R/R-32~1.4RE/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB="package name.dll" SHLIB_LIBADD='$(FLIBS)' OBJECTS="classTree.o regTree.o regrf.o rf.o rfsub.o rfutils.o"' had status 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'packagename'
* removing 'C:/Users/myusername/R/R-3.2.4revised/library/packagename'
Warning messages:
1: running command '"C:/Users/myusername/R/R-3.2.4revised/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\myusername\R\R-3.2.4revised\library" "C:/Users/myusername/packagename.tar.gz"' had status 1 
2: In install.packages("C:\\Users\\myusername\\packagename.tar.gz",  :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/myusername/packagename.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

I have search on internet and I found that maybe Rtools wasn’t installed and mapped with R. I tried to install it but at the end of the installation, a prompt saying the following appears :

> error creating registry key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SessionManager\Environment
>
> RegCreateKeyEx failed; code 5. Access is denied.

(Sorry I don't have 10+ reputation so I cannot upload a picture of the prompt)

Recall that I don't have administrator rights on this computer.

Maybe it is why I cannot install the package?

Any help would be very appreciated!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: It tells you linking failed. If that works on another machine then this is strictly local admin policy ...

Comment: Get your system admin to install Rtools for you. That's what I have to do at my work machine.

Comment: Do you think it is the only solution? I would rather manage this without having my IT department involved. Also, do you think this is the reason I cannot install my package ?

Comment: Well if you figure out how to compile C and C++ source code _without a compiler_ you'll be onto something.  Until then, do what we do and _install a compiler_ as @Roland suggested.